# jQuery - Remove comma from class names

Tags: jquery, replace, attributes

I have divs that have will sometimes have a 2 classes with a comma in between them. I did not code this by hand, it is generated by a webapp. I would like to remove the any commas in the class attribute and replace them with a space. How do I accomplish this? I have multiple classes, so I have to search for that character and replace that character only.

```
.each(function() {
    var $el = $(this),
        n = $el.attr("class").match(/cat-item-(.*)/)[1];

    $el.addClass(n);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery('whatever_youre_searching_to_update').each(function() {
    var _sCurrClasses = jQuery(this).attr('class');
    jQuery(this).attr('class', _sCurrClasses.replace(/,/g, ' '));
});
```

Comment: @Phorden If it works for you, please accept the answer so those looking for this in the future will know where to start and so Lawrence can receive credit.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
.each(function() {
    var $el = $(this),
          n = $el.attr("class");
    $el.attr('class', n.replace(/,/g,' ') );
});
```